# How to track data movement in YugabyteDB in multi-region replication

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

When I'm changing my placement info by adding a new datacenter, my data should start moving to accomplish my "rules". How can I track that movement?
`get_load_move_completion` This should give me some info?

Answer (score 0):

[`get_load_move_completion`](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/yb-admin/#get-load-move-completion) command in `yb-admin` only tracks load movement when a node is decommissioned (blacklisted). Essentially, it returns `1 -  (count of total replicas still present on the blacklisted nodes) / (total initial replica count on the blacklisted nodes)` as a percentage.

The `http://<yb-master-ip>:7000/tasks` endpoint in the master admin UI is where you would be able to see all the adds and removals.